# Why doesn't "Diff with Vim" command work?

Tags: windows-xp, vim, vimdiff

I am running gVim on WinXP.

I open a folder, select two files, and click "Diff with Vim". Screenshot:

[image: Vimdiff issue]

The gVim GUI starts up, with each of the files in its own tab. I notice that each tab is in DIFF mode. However, there is no comparison being made between the two tabs. Both files are completely different, yet there is no highlighting, nothing - just a gray line on the left, which I interpret to be the 'DIFF' mode:

[image: Result of diff]

What is going on? Is my **vimdiff** not working or is it something else?

---

**My SOLUTION**

Earlier, when I needed to [Open files in multiple tabs using the Windows Context Menu](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_files_in_multiple_tabs_using_the_Windows_Context_Menu), I followed a poster's advice and added the following line to my **.vimrc** file: `:autocmd BufReadPost * tab ball`

While that allowed me to open two files in separate tabs in a single Vim window, I lost the ability to diff the two files, if I wanted to. The solution to turn on both these features is to enable the `autocmd` above only in the case where I do not want to **diff** the two files, which happens when `&diff==0`. Thus, when I modified the code in my **.vimrc** file to the below, I regained my **Diff with Vim** functionality:

```
if (&diff==0)
    :autocmd BufReadPost * tab ball
endif
```

I've also added this solution to the comments portion of the [Vim Wikia link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_files_in_multiple_tabs_using_the_Windows_Context_Menu) mentioned above.

Comment: do you see anything happen at all? It sounds like you should reinstall gvim. This works for me on XP with the latest vim. When I try this I see a command window and then see the vim window in diff mode with the two files.

Comment: have you tried the command `:diffthis` in each tab? Although this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @David: the files are already in DIFF mode. But no, `:diffthis` does nothing new.

Comment: @IanNorton, why did you retag (from gvim to vim)? My understanding was that it is possible to run a [Win32 console executable](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/vim73_46w32.zip) version of vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is at best a hint, since I don't run windows or even use `gvim` under linux.  If the option `-p` is supplied to `vimdiff`, it will open its arguments in separate tabs.  Since diffing is only done across windows in the same tab, this effectively disables diffing.  `-p` still available because `vimdiff` just calls `vim -d ...`.  The `-p` tells vim to put each argument in a separate tab; it is pretty useful when normally invoking vim.  So it may be that you've somehow got vim configured to always do this.

I would check out what that `Diff with Vim` option actually does and trace it down to see if a batch file (or whatever they're called these days..) along the call chain is adding the `-p` option to your normal invocation of vim.  IIRC you can do this from Windows Explorer; there is an option in I think the View menu that shows you all filetypes.  You can view and edit the applications configured to "open" those filetypes.

Comment: Your post (as well as @sehe's) led me to the solution that works for me. I've posted it as an update to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, gvim defines a custom VimDiff() function in it's stock _vimrc (`:e +/Diff $MYVIMRC`)

You might want to check whether *it* works by doing

```
 :call VimDiff()
```

You need to check the actual function name and parameters (if any) since I don't have a windows machine handy at.m.

Comment: Thanks, I found the function definition in _vimrc. It is called `MyDiff`, and it did, in fact, work when I called it.